# iPad: retrieve filename of photo just taken using built-in camera and pass it to other function for further image processing

Tags: ios, ipad, image-processing

Hi all I am new to iOS programming and I am developing an iPad app which uses the iOS built-in camera to take photos and then use the photo taken for image processing (OpenCV) at BACKGROUND. There's no need to show the image process to the user. I would like to process the image once it is taken. But I don't know to how pass the photo just taken (the photo is saved in camera roll and the number(XXXX) of the filename IMG_XXXX.jpg keeps increasing). So how can I retrieve the filename of the photo just taken and pass it to the function for further image processing using OpenCV?

I have used the below two functions to take and save the photo.

```
// take photo
- (IBAction)captureCamera:(id)sender {
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
        _newMedia = YES; // a photo has been taken
    }
}

// save photo
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage])
    {
        UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        _imageView.image = image;
        if (_newMedia)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self,
                                           @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                           nil); }

    saveimg = true; // if an image is saved
    if (saveimg == true)
    {
        //imgprocess();    // pass the photo just taken for further image processing
    }

    saveimg = false; // reset it for next photo-taking
}
```

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I've removed the Xcode tag as this question is not directly related with Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

AssetLibrary can get you the enumeration capability on assets by:
`enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock:`
but now you have to try and see if it provides the last object path which is the latest one saved or not.

best of luck

Comment: thanks for your suggestion! I have read some references about the "ALAssetsLibrary" but still I can't figure out. Could you help to give some more hints for me to start with? many thanks again!